# Ionic4 / Angular 7 clase heredada con inyección de dependencias con Injector.get

Tags: angular, ionic, typescript

Estoy usando ionic4 y Angular 7.2.2, y creé una clase de un componente base para ser extendida por otros componentes y no tener que repetir ciertos importa en el constructor que siempre uso. Con el fin de evitar la inyección en el contructor y mantenerlo limpio para no tener queestar obligado a pasar de nuevo los parámetros al constructor base en la clase extendida, estoy usando Injector.get

El problema que tengo es que, cuando se usa de esta manera, muchos servicios injectados que funcionan bien si se inyectan en el constructor secundario, no funcionan o devuelven valores vacíos cuando se usan en el secundario, usando la referencia inicial creada en el constructor del padre.

Tras ejecutar en: **http://localhost:8101/home/4**
En home.page.ts no puedo leer, por ejemplo, activatedRoute params si tomo la referencia creada en el pasre desde el hijo. Obviamente, si lo inyecto el hijo directamente, funciona. Pero eso es precisamente lo que quiero evitar. Quiero tener activatedRoute y sin tener que inyectarlo de nuevo, en cualquier componente que herede de BasePage.

Muchas gracias,

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home/4', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'home/:id', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'},
];
```

**home.page.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {BasePage} from '../../tests/base.comp.test';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage extends BasePage {

    constructor(public ar: ActivatedRoute) {
        super();


        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
            (result) => {
                console.log(`PARAMS FROM inherited activatedRoute-> `, result); // -> outputs {} WRONG!

            }
        );

        ar.params.subscribe(
            (result) => {
                console.log(`Params from direct injection-> `, result); // -> outputs {id: "4"} Good!
            }
        );


    }

}
```

**home.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {HomePage} from './home.page';
import {BasePageModule} from '../../tests/base.test.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BasePageModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: '',
                component: HomePage
            }
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {
}
```

**base.test.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {IonicModule} from '@ionic/angular';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {BasePage} from './base.comp.test';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        IonicModule,
        FormsModule,
    ],
    declarations: [BasePage],
    providers: [],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        IonicModule,
        FormsModule
    ]
})
export class BasePageModule {
}
```

**base.comp.test.ts**

```
import {Component, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {AppInjectorTest} from './app.injector.test';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-base',
    template: '',
})
export class BasePage {

    public injector: Injector;
    public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute;

    constructor() {
        const injector = AppInjectorTest.getInjector();
        this.activatedRoute = injector.get(ActivatedRoute);
    }

}
```

**app.injector.test.ts**

```
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';

export class AppInjectorTest {

    private static injector: Injector;

    static setInjector(injector: Injector) {
        AppInjectorTest.injector = injector;
    }

    static getInjector(): Injector {
        return AppInjectorTest.injector;
    }

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Injector} from '@angular/core';

import {Platform} from '@ionic/angular';
import {SplashScreen} from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import {StatusBar} from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import {AppInjectorTest} from '../tests/app.injector.test';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(
        private platform: Platform,
        private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
        private statusBar: StatusBar,
        private injector: Injector
    ) {
        this.initializeApp();
        AppInjectorTest.setInjector(injector);
    }

    initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.statusBar.styleDefault();
            this.splashScreen.hide();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido Martín, por favor traduce tu pregunta...  Estás es SO español

Comment: Lo siento. Se me ha debido de poner en español automáticamente. Yo lo suelo usar en inglés. No obstante, he traducido la pregunta al español tal y como me has indicado. Gracias!